# How to speed up saving a list as template

Tags: 2010, list-template, powershell

I want to save a library as a template.

For this I use the following PowerShell code

```
    $id = [Guid]::NewGuid()     
    $templateName = [String]::Format("{0}-{1}",$list.Title,$id.ToString());
    $templateFileName = $templateName;       
    $destinationListDescription = $list.Description;  
    $list.SaveAsTemplate($templateFileName, $templateName, $list.Description, $false)
    $listTemplate =  $site.GetCustomListTemplates($SPWeb)[$templateName]
    $SPWeb.Lists.Add($Destination, $Destination, $listTemplate) | out-null;   
    $SPWeb.Update()
```

In our development, test and acception enviroments everything went well but in our production environment the process of saving the template takes more than an hour.
The only difference is that the library in production contains many many documents

Also when I try to save the list from the browser this also takes ages.

Does anyone now why saving the list as template takes so long and is there an other, **fast** way to save the list as a template?

Comment: It's not directly stated or commented on. Is saving the list data a requirement? Or are you even saving the data with the list?

Comment: No the data is not saved. Only the design. If the data was saved then it was not strange why it takes so long.

Comment: I was assuming that might be the case, but the data not being saved wasn't explicitly stated. You may want to add Patch level to this question in case it is version specific or some type of regression.